# Remove data using the common data from another data frame python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have two dataframes:

```
Date = [np.datetime64('2021-07-21'), np.datetime64('2021-07-21'), np.datetime64('2021-07-21'), np.datetime64('2021-07-21'),
       np.datetime64('2021-07-22'), np.datetime64('2021-07-22'), np.datetime64('2021-07-22'), np.datetime64('2021-07-22'),
       np.datetime64('2021-07-23'),np.datetime64('2021-07-23')]
UID = [81.322, 81.322, 81.452, 81.552, 82.522, 82.562, 82.722, 81.723, 81.322, 81.332 ]
data_1 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': Date, 'UID': UID})
data_1

    Date        UID
0   2021-07-21  81.322
1   2021-07-21  81.322
2   2021-07-21  81.452
3   2021-07-21  81.552
4   2021-07-22  82.522
5   2021-07-22  82.562
6   2021-07-22  82.722
7   2021-07-22  81.723
8   2021-07-23  81.322
9   2021-07-23  81.332
```

and

```
Date = [np.datetime64('2021-07-21'), np.datetime64('2021-07-21'), np.datetime64('2021-07-22'), np.datetime64('2021-07-23')]
UID = [81.452,81.552, 82.562, 81.322 ]
data_2 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': Date, 'UID': UID})
data_2


Date    UID
0   2021-07-21  81.452
1   2021-07-21  81.552
2   2021-07-22  82.562
3   2021-07-23  81.322
```

I want to remove the columns from data_1 that are in data_2 but keep the current indexes in data one, so my output would be:

```
    Date        UID
0   2021-07-21  81.322
1   2021-07-21  81.322
4   2021-07-22  82.522
6   2021-07-22  82.722
7   2021-07-22  81.723
9   2021-07-23  81.332
```

I have tried concatenating them and then using`drop_duplicates(data_1, keep = False)`but that ends up removing rows 0 and 1 too. I cant figure out a way, please let me know how I can do this

Comment: based on Date & UID? if so this should work `pd.merge(data_1,data_2,on=['Date','UID'],how='left',indicator=True).query("_merge=='both'").drop('_merge',axis=1)`

Comment: I would strongly advise against using exact equal on `float` dtype

Comment: @QuangHoang in pandas or in general?

Comment: @Umar.H in general.

Comment: @QuangHoang personally have no issue if I can control the precision of the float/decimal  in my given table understand that pandas won't force a precision but it can be done before any merge